# Sphinx (for Python) - Search bar disappeared

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm new to Sphinx and having completed my documentation I noticed the search bar has disappeared when it was there previously.

I haven't (knowingly) changed anything in the `conf.py` file and am not sure why this has happened.

Does anybody know how to get it back?

Comment: Let's see your `index.rst`. Also did you modify or switch to a different theme?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

```
* :ref:`modindex`
```

In the file which will named `./index.rst`

From the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6.3/markup/toctree.html#special-names) ...

> - The special document names (and pages generated for them) are:
>
>   `genindex, modindex, search`
>
>   These are used for the general index, the Python module index, and the
>     search page, respectively.
>
>   The general index is populated with entries from modules, all
>     index-generating object descriptions, and from index directives.

Comment: I added the `* :ref:\`modindex\`` code snippet to my `index.rst` file however the quicksearch bar is still not appearing?

Comment: try `make clean`?